# sharepoint opens documents in Read only mode for users with office 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I had a strange issue with Sharepoint 2010 where users with contribute permissions when they try to open a document it always open in read only mode. I reviewed the farm configuration and everything seems to be fine. I also noticed that users with office 2013 are able to open and edit the documents with no issues. I knew at that point that it was related to the client office version and not Sharepoint. After a lot of research I found the solution.

- On the client computer experiencing the issue click on "RUN" then type "RegEdit".
- go to this path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet
- Right click and create new "DWORD" entry and give it a name of "FSSHTTPOff"
- Double click the new entry and enter 1 for the value.

Once done you might need to reboot the computer but not always required. once done the user with office 2010 will be able to edit documents in Sharepoint.

Please note that to apply this change to all users, your IT Admin will have to push out this change as a policy change on the network.

Hope this solution will help someone out there :)

Eyad

Comment: It's cool to come and create a question/answer to a problem you've solved, but you should do it as a question and an answer, so that the solution can be marked as an answer. Second, there is a site specific to SharePoint - sharepoint.stackexchange.com, and since this is a configuration and not a programming problem it definitely belongs there.

Answer (score 4):

This workaround worked for me; despite the title. :)

[Excel opens in Read-Only after upgrading to Windows 8 with Office 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_made_easy/2013/02/03/excel-opens-in-read-only-after-upgrading-to-windows-8-with-office-2010)

For comparison, I'm on Windows 10 with Office 2016.

**Steps** (copied from the above link):

> Create the below registry key. This is Client machine issue, NOT
>   SharePoint Server related.
>
> 1. Open regedit.exe
> 2. Naviagate to following key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet]
>      “FSSHTTPOff” = dword:0000001
> 3. Click Edit Menu -> New -> DWORD with name of “FSSHTTPOff” (without quotes)
> 4. Click on “FSSHTTPOff” and enter value of 1
> 5. Close any Office Applications and browser sessions
> 6. Try to repro the problem

Comment: @GhostCat An excellent point. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the suggestion. Should have included this originally. My bad.

Comment: Brought me an entry in the late answer queue; and an upvote for you. All fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by SharePoint having approval of version set active.

Library settings, versioning control settings, Require content approval for submitted items is set to YES, must be set to NO, if you want to use explorer to edit files directly.

Thanks